# NCrunch showing brace for a loop as untested

Tags: ncrunch

Consider the block of code shown in the image below:

[image]

There is the one pesky black/'this line of code is not covered by any tests' dot.

Anyone able to shed any light on how this is not covered by any tests, considering it is referring to the closing brace of a `foreach` loop?

If the rest of the loop is covered (all green), surely the end brace is hit when exiting `foreach`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never used `NCrunch`, but from my experience with other code coverage products I would guess that you do not have a test case where the loop is exited the "regular" way without hitting the `break` statement.

Comment: Sounds very plausible, I'll review the test cases tomorrow to confirm.. thanks!

Comment: Should just confirm this was indeed the reason. None of the test cases we had went through the loop without hitting the break point.